# SQL query optimization - multiple query or DAYOFYEAR()?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to run queries with several conditions which will result large dataset. Whereas all the conditions are straight forward, I need advice regarding 2 issues in terms of speedoptimization:

1) If I need to run those queries between 1st Apr till 20th June of each year for last 10 years, I have 2 options in my knowledge:

a. Run the query 10 times

```
$year = 2015;
$start_month_date = "-04-01";
$end_month_date = "-06-20";
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
  $start = $year.$start_month_date;
  $end = $year.$start_month_date;
  $result = mysql_query("....... WHERE .... AND `event_date` BETWEEN $start AND $end");
  // PUSH THE RESULT TO AN ARRAY
  $year = $year - 1;
}
```

b. Run the query single time, however query will compare by DayOfYear (hence each date has to be converted to DayOfYear by the query)

```
$start = Date("z", strtotime("2015-04-01")) + 1;
$end = Date("z", strtotime("2015-06-20")) + 1;
$result = mysql_query("....... WHERE .... AND DAYOFYEAR(`event_date`) BETWEEN $start AND $end");
```

I am aware of the 1 day difference in day count for leap year with other years, but I can live with that. I am sensing 1.b is more optimized, just want to verify.

2) I have a large query with 2 sub query. When I want to limit the result by date, I should put the conditions inside or outside the sub query?

a. Inside sub query means it has to validate the condition twice

```
SELECT X.a,X.b,Y.c FROM 
(SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `event_date` BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate' AND `case` = 'AAA' AND .......) X
(SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `event_date` BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate' AND `case` = 'BBB' AND .......) Y
WHERE X.`event_date` = Y.`event_date` AND ........... ORDER BY `event_date`
```

b. Outside sub query means it will validate once, but has to join a larger dataset (for which I need to set SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1)

```
SELECT X.a,X.b,Y.c FROM 
(SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `case` = 'AAA' AND .......) X
(SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `case` = 'BBB' AND .......) Y
WHERE X.`event_date` = Y.`event_date` AND X.`event_date` BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate' AND ........... ORDER BY `event_date`
```

Again, in my opinion 2.a is more optimized, but requesting your advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Running the queries 10 times with `event_date BETWEEN $start AND $end` will be faster when the SQL engine can take advantage of an index on `event_date`.  This could be significant, but it depends on the rest of the query.

Also, because you are ordering the entire data set, running 10 queries is likely to be a bit faster.  That's because sorting is O(n log(n)), meaning that it takes longer to sort larger data sets.  As an example, sorting 100 rows might take X time units.  Sorting 1000 rows might take X * 10 * log(10) time units.  But, sorting 100 rows 10 times takes just X * 10 (this is for explanatory purposes).

(2) Don't use subqueries if you can avoid them in MySQL.  The subqueries are materialized, which adds additional overhead.  Plus, they then prevent the use of indexes.  If you need to use subqueries, filter the data as much as possible in the subquery.  This reduces the data that needs to be stored.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. that's why i always take advise here in SO ... just some confirmations: (1) Basically the query is same as example 2, with 2 sub queries. I have conditions on 3 fields, apart from the event_date, I just use to extra conditions: case ='A' and month='JUL', some thing like that. All these 3 fields are indexed in mysql database table. So, I'll be using 10 queries method as per your advice.

Comment: (2) So, I'll put as many conditions as possible inside sub queries (if I need to use them) rather than putting them at the end on the joined data set

Comment: If you have equality conditions, then an index on `case, month, event_date` would be a good choice of index.

Comment: thanks ... I do have index on those 3 .. however, month and case is equality conditioned, event_date is bounded by BETWEEN

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have lots rows over 10 years otherwise that wouldn't be much of an issue.

Now the best bet is to do a couple explain on the different queries you plan to use, that will probably tell you which index it can use as currently we don't know them (you didn't post the structure of the table)

1.b. use a function in where clause so it will be terrible as it won't be able to use index for date (assuming there is one). So this will read the entire table

One thing that you could do, is ask the database to join the resultset of the 10 queries together using UNION. Mysql would join the result instead of php... (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

2 - As gordon said, filter data as much as possible. However instead of trying option blindly you can use EXPLAIN and the database will help you decide which one make the most sense.

Comment: okay, basically I need to put condition on 3 fields, and all those 3 fields are indexed.

Comment: thanks a lot .. both of you are agreed on same method (and one is opposite to what I was thinking :). So I'll go with what you guys have suggested

Comment: By experience, I recall that mysql was sometimes not using the index when the date range was above ~30 days (that was mysql 5.1) so even if that looks like the best index it was doing something unexpected. So you should check which index it's using. It won't be able to use all 3 :)